# Not formatting a partition while installing Ubuntu but still data getting lost from that partition!

Tags: system-installation, data-loss

I'd Ubuntu 13.10 on my system with separate `/home` partition for my data. Now I reinstalled the same O.S. In the option while installing, I selected `something else` & there specified to format all partitions (/, /var, /tmp, /boot) except `/home`. Now when my system was installed, I found the data was lost on the home partition. I wondered as I had unchecked for formatting that partition while installation.

To test it again, I created a file in `/home`. Then using my bootable usb flash drive, I reinstalled the O.S. This time also I unchecked `/home` for formatting. But still afterwards I found the file I created on the home partition was lost.

Where am I thinking wrong? I thought it was a good method of installation to preserve home data but it's not working!!

> EDIT#1

Yes I got clue from a comment. The problem is something else. Yes it's mounting on /home, that's no problem.

See what has happened! In the 1st system (Ubuntu 13.10) I'd logged in with the name of "ravi". I'd much data in the subdirectories of /home/ravi.
Then I upgraded the system to 14.04 which didn't work, so I installed back the earlier O.S. (i.e. 13.10.) by keeping the same /home partition. This time while installing I changed the login name as "bholu". Now after getting installed & logging in as "bholu", I checked my home directory & subdirectories but didn't find any data.
Then to further test, I created a file in home directory & reinstalled the O.S. with the same /home. Now this time I changed the login name to "bholua". Again now I didn't find the file I created earlier. So, I'd that doubt that the data are getting lost.

Now after reading a comment, it striked my mind & I checked my /home folder. There all the 3 names were present.

```
bholua@bholua-Aspire-5315:/home$ ls
bholu  bholua  lost+found  ravi
bholua@bholua-Aspire-5315:/home$
```

Now when I move to one username "ravi" , I see the below contents there.

```
bholua@bholua-Aspire-5315:/home/ravi$ ll
total 12
dr-x------ 3 bholua bholua 4096 Jun 25 02:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   4096 Jul 27 23:39 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   56 Jun 25 02:04 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop*
drwx------ 3 bholua bholua 4096 Jun 25 02:25 .cache/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   30 Jun 25 02:04 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/ravi/.ecryptfs/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   29 Jun 25 02:04 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/ravi/.Private/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   52 Jun 25 02:04 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Now see the content of the other username "bholu". It's the same here.

```
bholua@bholua-Aspire-5315:/home/ravi$ ll /home/bholu
total 12
dr-x------ 3 bholua bholua 4096 Jul 28 03:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   4096 Jul 27 23:39 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   56 Jul 28 03:13 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop*
drwx------ 3 bholua bholua 4096 Jul 28 03:16 .cache/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   31 Jul 28 03:13 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/bholu/.ecryptfs/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   30 Jul 28 03:13 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/bholu/.Private/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bholua bholua   52 Jul 28 03:13 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Now the point is how to access those data created under username of "ravi" & "bholu"! It seems I'd earlier enabled encryption of my home directory.
linuxubuntu ravisingh1 is online now    Report This Post

Comment: 13.10 has reached it's End of Live and is no longer supported. I recommend switching to an LTS Version. (12.04 or 14.04).

Comment: This should not happen. Did you tell the installer to also mount your HOME partition to **mountpoint** `/home`?

Comment: @Takkat Please see my edit